# Azure event hub send message with bearer token

Tags: azure-eventhub

Hi I have obtained a bearer token to send message to event hub after registering an application in azure active directory. I attempted to send a message using event hub message endpoint but constantly getting 500 error. Is there any place where I can see the detailed error or is this style of using bearer token to send message is supported at all?

Comment: can you please add the steps or code how obtain bearer token?

Comment: Which SDK are you using to send messages?

Comment: I am not using any SDK. I am trying to use their rest api to send message

Comment: @qamar, please add more details, like how do you use the api, how  to obtain bearer token. Then we can repro / solve the issue more easier.

Comment: An HTTP 500 would typically indicate that authorization was accepted.   Generally, you would see either a 401 (we don't know who you are) or 403 (we know who you are and you are not allowed to do this)  if your token was rejected.   Based on that, I would take a look at the request that you're making; something would seem to be incorrect but not obvious enough that the service was able to reject it by validation.

Comment: That's my guess too!! It could be the payload not sure whats wrong. I'll update the question tomorrow